# How to create mapped index with specified name using spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: kotlin, elasticsearch, indexing, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an index using indexOperations. I have the following code:

```
val indexOperations = template.indexOps(SmartStoreNew::class.java)
indexOperations.create()
```

Where SmarStoreNew is @Document object.
So my question is how do I specify the index name using such construction?

Answer (score 0):

The index name is taken from the `@Document` annotation of the `SmartStoreNew` class. If you want to specify a different index name than the one from this annotation, you can do

```
val indexOperations = template.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of("index-name"))
indexOperations.create()
```

**Edit 07.09.2021**

An index name "smart_store_new_2021-09-07T22:10:58.541117". would be invalid, please check (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-api-path-params) what characters are allowed in an index name.

Besides that, you can use a SpEL expression in the `@Document` annotation, please check the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.4/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations) or read my blog post about that (https://www.sothawo.com/2020/07/how-to-provide-a-dynamic-index-name-in-spring-data-elasticsearch-using-spel/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My idea is to create index name according to current time, like:
index.name == "smart_store_new_2021-09-07T22:10:58.541117". So I want to know how to specify index name before or may be after creation using timestamp.